# Getting facebook id of all persons who shared a particular video uploaded on youtube

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, youtube-api

Let's say I uploaded a video on youtube and someone shared that video on facebook by clicking the "share" button on youtube. How could I get the facebook id or username of that person. I  tried using the youtube gdata api and also tried facebook graph api, but could not succeed. I am quite sure that it is possible as i have seen this functionality implemented on a website.

Comment: Where have you seen this?  I'd be _very_ surprised if Facebook allowed  you to get that kind of data.  (It seems iffy on privacy grounds, if nothing else.)

Comment: yeah Louis, I am in complete agreement with you on this. I too think that fb does not allow to get this kind of data. I guess it could be achieved by youtube api but don't know exactly how. I have seen this functionality on a site which tracks a particular youtube video, and shows the name and fb id of the users who shared it by clicking the youtube share button. I implemented the same functionality for twitter shares, and that was quite easy because twitter provides the search by videoId functionality but facebook does not.

Answer (score 1):

This is only possible for the developers of the YouTube Facebook application to know about. You *can* get all *friends of the current user* who shared a particular video.

For example,

`SELECT link_id, owner, owner_comment, created_time, title, summary, url, picture, image_urls FROM link WHERE owner in (select uid2 from friend where uid1 = me() limit 5) and strpos(url, 'lmDTSQtK20c') >= 0`

Not quite efficient but it works.

A second way would be to use /search

`/search?q=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YOUTUBEID&type=post`

That should search public posts

Comment: thanks for your reply but my requirement is to get all fb users who shared a particular youtube video.

Comment: @user1304683 Well I'm not sure how to rephrase it. The API doesn't give you access to the entire Facebook userbase, just some public connection objects and those users who added your app. You cannot get that information (Facebook users who shared a YouTube video). It would be a breach of Facebook privacy policy if that was possible and not how the API was set up to work. The share button doesn't give access to that information.